# Empty parameter functions passing as arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here are two functions to be used as UDFs:

```
def nextString(): String = Random.nextString(10)
def plusOne(a: Int): Int = a + 1

def udfString = udf(nextString)
def udfInt = udf(plusOne)
```

If I try to use withColumn, myUDF1 will work perfectly fine with udfInt, but throws: **can't use Char in Schema** for udfString

Probably cause it uses (Int) => (Int) for udfInt type, which is what udf expects

But treats nextString as type String, which obviously leads to an assumption, that I am trying to extract Chars when I apply the function.

It will work if I do something like:

```
def myUDF: () => String = udf(() => nextString)
```

Which seems ugly for something that simple. Is there any way to pass udfString as a function, not as String?

Comment: I would just do `def udfString = udf(() => Random.nextString(10))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you write the following code:

```
def udfString = udf(nextString)
```

it's the same as writing

```
val s = nextString
def udfString = udf(s)
```

this compiles because a string is also a function of `Int => Char` (see [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#apply(index:Int):Char))

you can tell the compiler that you are passing a function to the udf by:

```
def udfString = udf(nextString _)
```